# Rails ActionMailer receive method does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm following the Rails official doc about [action mailer receive method](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionmailer#receiving-emails) and testing with the `rails runner 'UserMailer.receive(STDIN.read)'` command but **nothing happens**.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper EmailHelper
  default from: "xx@xxx.xxx"

  def user_created(params)
    @user = User.find params[0]
    @creator = User.find params[1]
    if @user && @creator
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: "......").deliver
    else
        logger.info "......"
    end
  end

  def receive(email)
    puts YAML::dump email
  end
end
```

Here's the detail about my Rails app

```
rails@4.1.6
actionmailer@4.1.5
```

The `UserMailer` actually sends emails but can not receive them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to refer to Action Mailer Basics Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails

I'm interpreting their suggestion to mean: Configure your mail server/process to "pipe into" a Rails runner script... That would account for the STDIN.read; the contents of the mail message would be passed into the script.

HTH.